# Image url changing while cliking onRecyclerView item

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

```
 private DisplayImageOptions options;
@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false);


    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,200,200,false);
                }
            })
            .build();

    TaskViewHolder tvh = new TaskViewHolder(v);
    return tvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.task_title.setText(tasks.get(position).get_title());
    holder.task_date_to_end.setText(tasks.get(position).get_description());

       try {
        /*Picasso.with(context).load(tasks.get(position).get_url_to_icon()).resize(200, 200).into(holder.task_url_to_icon);*/
      ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(tasks.get(position).get_url_to_icon(),holder.task_url_to_icon,options);
    } catch (Exception e) {}


    if (tasks.get(position).isSelected()) {
        holder.task_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));
    } else {
        holder.task_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

Im using picasso library to change url to image. While i selecting smth on list the image on the other items changes randomly (always changing with existing urls from another items)

EDIT: Im tried to use Universal-Image-Loader, but i,ve got nothing. Its probably implementation problem.

Comment: Do you have any on click code??

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/f96qv2rhn/

Its look like this. The task without image get it randomly from the other from the list

Comment: I recommend you using Universal Image loader. If you don't know how to use i can give a example..!

Comment: I will be appreciated. I tried to use it but i got only one image and info that ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. Should I initialize it in my adapter class?

Comment: Show me the code..Please update the question.. I will try to correct it..!! :)

Comment: Ok, I update my question.

Comment: Still nothing is viewed :/

Comment: it is not showing `ic_launcher` too???? Something is wrong that out of my vision here..!!

Comment: eh i dont know what can It be. Here is all my code if you find some time maybe the problem is in the other class. https://github.com/KamilPieta/Android/tree/master/TasksManager

Comment: got your problem.. and solved it.. posting your task adapter..!!

Comment: Thats helpt thanks!

Comment: See this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235. Please mark the answer as correct..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder> {

List<Task> tasks;
protected Context context;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
public TaskAdapter(List<Task> tasks, Context context) {

    //-----------This lines---------------//

    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()).diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    //-----------This lines---------------//
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.face)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.face)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.face).cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).build();
    this.tasks = tasks;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false);



    TaskViewHolder tvh = new TaskViewHolder(v);
    return tvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.task_title.setText(tasks.get(position).get_title());
    holder.task_date_to_end.setText(tasks.get(position).get_description());
    holder.task_url_to_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       try {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(tasks.get(position).get_url_to_icon(),holder.task_url_to_icon,options);

    } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("EXP",e.getMessage());
    }

    if (tasks.get(position).isSelected()) {
        holder.task_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));
    } else {
        holder.task_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
public void setSelected(int pos) {
    try {
        tasks.get(pos).setSelected(!tasks.get(pos).isSelected());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void add(int position, Task task) {
    tasks.add(task);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void deleteSelectedItems() {
    for(int i=0;i<getItemCount();++i){
        if(tasks.get(i).isSelected()==true)
        {   tasks.remove(i);
             notifyItemRemoved(i);i=0;
           }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}
}
```

The code surrounded with `//-----------This lines---------------//` comment needed to be written once when application gets started. If you have any `ApplicationLoader` class then put this in that. No need to write these line every time when adapter initializes..!!

Or leaving them as they are will not make any difference. It was just a clarification.