# How to load JPEG images to ImageView using Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

For the first time I'm getting issue while using `Picasso` Image library into my project.

I'm having my `JPEG image` into server. This is my code.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://beta.receiptmatch.com/admin/webresources/images/no_company_image.jpg").into(itemViewHolder.imgLogo);
```

Picasso failed to load this image into ImageView. It doesn't print any warnings/issue in log tracker.

**Note:** Problem only with .jpeg/.jpg extension url. Url with .png extension working fine.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using Universal Image loader. see my answer here.:http://stackoverflow.com/a/37479618/6127411

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. But I used Picasso throughout my Project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the INTERNET permission to your code

Comment: can you post your layout file as well?